# How to use jQuery on widget admin page

Tags: wordpress

I have a lengthy form config for my widget so I thought about using radio buttons to hide and show the relevant input fields instead of having them all after each other. But it doesn't seem to work. I suppose it is because the form is loaded with ajax? Is there a way to get it to work?

Take a look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/JmVL3/

Comment: So your code works in JSFiddle but not in your WordPress admin, right?

Did you make sure that jQuery is loaded before your code in your admin area (I've had that problem personally before)?

Let's say it is, do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: jQuery loads just fine because wordpress use it to expand the widget settings form. And no, there are no console errors.

Comment: Also, it works to alert a message when clicking the radio buttons. But it doesn't work to show/hide input fields.

Comment: Another thing. It also works if i enable accessibility mode.